# Need help writing a command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to set up a custom sword shop on my server with command blocks, and i'm stuck trying to spawn a custom model, data item already renamed/colored.

You can do this:
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{CustomModelData:1000001}

And you can do this:
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"Ancient Sword","italic":false,"bold":true,"color":"light_purple"}'}}

Is there a way to combine the two, or chain 2 command blocks to get the same result? I'm not sure if I explained it well enough, but I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things you want to combine are the NBT of the items. NBT is basically a list of tags, so separate each tag with commas like this:

`/give @s minecraft:diamond_sword{CustomModelData:1000001,display:{Name:'{"text":"Ancient Sword","italic":false,"bold":true,"color":"light_purple"}'}}`

Comment: Hey, nisse, welcome to Arqade!  You could improve this answer by explaining what you did to combine the two, so that future readers can understand and use your answer to help themselves.